# Binding items to listbox adds them vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I have a question. When `Binding` items to a `ListBox` it adds them vertically. For example where `ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Name}"`, and `Name` is `Bill`, I get the output in `ListBox` for each char in on line (like this: B\ni\nl\nl). Where am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableColl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="244" Margin="313,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
    class Customer
    {
        public string Name{get; set;}
    }

    class Customers
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> customerOC{get; set;}
        public Customers()
        {
            customerOC = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        }
        public void AddCustomer(Customer c)
        {
             customerOC.Add(c);
        }
    }

public partial class MainWindow:Window
{
    Customers customers{get; set;}
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customers = new Customers();

        customers.AddCustomer(new Customer(){Name = "Frank"});

        this.DataContext = customers;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the constructor of the class Customers, what is 'customer'? I see no definition of this variable.

Comment: Sorry it was meant to be customerOC. Edited*

Comment: Can you show your full XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataContext` is set to customers. The `ItemsSource` should be set to the `ObservableCollection` and `DisplayMemberPath` is for showing the right property of your Customer.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding customerOC}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```